# Event Delegation/API access

Tags: javascript, api, event-handling

I'm building a news aggregator for a personal project and it involves getting information from an api.  The api has different categories to choose from. Business, Sports, Tech, etc. etc. I have a separate page for each category.  I've build the homepage with top news stories that don't involve pulling info from a specific category and it works fine.  I'm having trouble when trying to click a link to another page. So for example,  when I click the link to go to the business page I'd like to change the "category" in the api header to business and then display top stories from the business category.

The relevant HTML

```
<ul class="nav-list" id="nav-list">
            <li class="home"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li class="business"><a href="business.html" class="business">Business</a></li>
            <li class="entertainment"><a href="entertainment.html">Entertainment</a></li>
            <li class="health"><a href="health.html">Health</a></li>
            <li class="science"><a href="science.html">Science</a></li>
            <li class="sports"><a href="sports.html">Sports</a></li>
            <li class="technology"><a href="technology">Technology</a></li>
          </ul>
```

I'm only testing with the "home" and "business" classes as of now so those are the focus.

The relevant JavaScript

```
let newCategory = '';
const navList = document.getElementById('nav-list');
```

The API access

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url + 'category=' + newCategory, true);
xhr.onload = function () {
  var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
  console.log(data);
  for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    cardTitle[i].innerHTML = data.articles[i].title;
    cardSubTitle[i].innerHTML = data.articles[i].description;
    source[i].innerHTML = data.articles[i].source.name;
    if (data.articles[i].urlToImage != null) {
      image[i].src = data.articles[i].urlToImage;
    }else {
      image[i].src = 'no-image.jpg';
    }
  }
};

xhr.send();
```

The event listener

```
navList.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  console.log(e.target.nodeName);
  if (e.target.className == 'business') {
    console.log('hello');
    newCategory = 'business';
    console.log(newCategory);
  }
}, false);
```

I've set up the `newCategory` variable to try and pass it in through `xhr.open()`. When I declare the `newCategory` and set it to "business" right away the variable works.  The API gives me news from business category. Unfortunately it gives me the business news on every page.

Also, when I test my event listener, it seems to be working ok.  When I `console.log(e.target.nodeName);` it returns "A". `console.log('hello');` returns "hello" and `console.log(newCategory);` returns "business".  The only problem is that when I click the link to the business page everything in the event listener works except the page doesn't display the business news.  It just displays whats on the homepage.

** Note**  Everything I'm logging to the console only displays for a split second when I click then disappears so I'm not sure if the business news is only displaying for a split second as well.

Any insight would be great.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing more code, it looks like your code is navigating away from the page to the link in the href.  The navList you have defined to listen on the click event is receiving the click event from the link that has bubbled up.  By the time it bubbles up the default behavior of the link which is to navigate away from the page has already taken place.  You could add the code below to prevent the default behavior of all the links in navList:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#nav-list li a').forEach((val)=>{
  val.addEventListener('click', (e)=> e.preventDefault());
});
```

Also if the xhr request isn't wrapped in a function then the xhr can only be called the only time.